# What is the correct way to install Maven and Eclipse?

Tags: software-installation, eclipse, maven-3

I have installed Maven and Eclipse using the Software Center in Ubuntu 12.04.

There is no sign of Maven integration in Eclipse. ("new Maven project" and such)

What is the correct way to install? (to get Maven Eclipse integration)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In addition to installing the `maven` package and the `eclipse` package, and all their dependencies, you need to install the m2e extension. The best way to do this is using the Eclipse Marketplace, but the marketplace is not installed by default in the Ubuntu package.

### Install the Eclipse Marketplace

1. Open Eclipse, go to **Help** -> **Install New Software...**
2. Select **All Available Sites** in the **Work with** dropdown menu.
3. Wait for the list of software to populate; sometimes it takes a very long time.
4. Expand the **General Purpose Tools** group, and tick **Marketplace Client**.
5. Click **Next**, and again, accept the terms and conditions and click **Finish**.

This will install the marketplace. You will need to restart Eclipse for the change to take effect.

### Install m2e

1. Open Eclipse, go to **Help** -> **Eclipse Marketplace...**
2. Wait for it to finish loading.
3. Enter "maven" in the search box and press return.
4. Click the **Install** button next to **Maven Integration for Eclipse** by Eclipse.org (NB: there is a similar item above called "Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP" by Red Hat, Inc; this is *not* the correct one).

Again, you will need to restart Eclipse for this to take effect.

Comment: There was no _Help -> Eclipse Marketplace_ in my installation. I went to _Help -> Install New Software..._ and added the repository
http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e  
  
I did get maven integration to the menus. I'll report if I encounter any obvious problems.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice that the marketplace is not installed by default. I have updated my answer to explain how to do this starting from the default Eclipse package. Although an additional step, installing the marketplace is beneficial anyway and avoids having to manually add extra repositories.

Comment: Okay, looks good now. Flagged as accepted.

Comment: Is it still the case that Ubuntu doesn't package the Eclipse Marketplace?  I wanted to check if there was a package to install instead of doing it from inside eclipse.