# Install Eclipse Marketplace - which Maven plugin for my configuration?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, maven-3

I've had some struggles getting Java, Eclipse and Maven to work properly on my configuration.

environment: 
Ubuntu 12.04 
Java 8 
Eclipse Indigo 3.7 
Maven 3.0

Task: Install Maven plug in through Eclipse. 
Question: Do you know which plug in works for my config?

Steps: 
1) Installed Eclipse & Maven via Software center. 
 
2) Following this [AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141204/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-maven-and-eclipse?rq=1) "Install the Eclipse Marketplace" in step 4 the options below are presented:

1 -Maven Integration for Eclipse (Luna 4.4); 
2- Maven (Java EE) Integration for Eclipse WTP (Luna 4.4);
3 -Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP (Juno 3.8/ 4.2) 
4 -Maven Integration for Eclipse (Luna 4.4 and newer)

I'm not entirely clear on how plugins work; if I should be using the newest released plug in even if it's newer than my software version? Or the one closest to my Eclipse version?

Help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the plunge and tried 
*"3 -Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP (Juno 3.8/ 4.2) "*

and it worked. I'll circle back if any errors happen in relation to this plug in.